# Open variable in readonly split window in vim?

Tags: json, http, vim

Here is the current code that i am using in vim

```
function! NpmDocs()
  let package_name = input('Package name: ')
  if package_name != ''
    let url = 'https://registry.npmjs.org/' . package_name
    let res = webapi#http#get(url)
    let obj  =webapi#json#decode(res.content)
    echo obj.readme
  endif
endfunction
```

The problem is the `echo` part. Basically i want to open the output in a new split window like the one we get in `help` page. Can someone please help me out with how to go with it?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス not working still the same result

Comment: `redir @z | echo obj.readme | redir END | new | put! z` with this command it should redirect the output of `echo` to the new window.  What result did you get exactly ?

Comment: its not working with obj.readme, i tried that with `echo "hello"`, i get result in split fine but some issue with readme file

Comment: What is the `readme` variable ?

Comment: String response from api

Comment: Where it is defined is it global in the script ?

Comment: No inside function only.

Comment: register is working properly, i just printed the output from z

Comment: You are concatenating `obj` to something which is not defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137353/discussion-between-georoot-and-meninx-).